# How to activate validators only on button click

Tags: asp.net, validation, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using Ajax Control Toolkit validators on an ASP.NET page, whose values can be saved by clicking a Submit button. The page can have distinct sections depending on two radio buttons (so the radio buttons have Autopostback set to true). My problem is that when I click the radio buttons to switch sections (so on postback) the validators are activated and appear as red. I don't want this behavior. I want the validation to be done only when the user clicks Submit.

EDIT: The cause was found. Somewhere inside the page, a control was performing Page.Validate().

Answer (score 2):

Make radio button Causes validation to false.

Example

```
<asp:radiobutton runat="server" CausesValidation="False">
</asp:radiobutton>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

use `validationgroup` property of `Ajax Control Toolkit validators` and `Submit button`.

Comment: the submit button has the same validationgroup as the validators...it works if i just click the button; my problem is that the validation is activated when a radio button is clicked, even though the radio buttons don't have any validation

Comment: then you can use `causesvalidation=false` property for other controls where you don't want to show these validation error messages.

Comment: I do want the error messages when submit is clicked; i just don't want them when a postback occurs; i edited the question in the meantime